# Android - Adding HeaderView to ListView throws ClassCastException

Tags: android, listview, header, classcastexception, layoutparams

Anyone know how to properly add a HeaderView to a ListView in android?  This is what I have:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_post_note, commentsListView, false);
```

after that I setup an ImageView and a couple TextView's that are already part of the adapter_post_note layout by setting the image resource and/or text. then here is where I add the HeaderView

```
commentsListView.addHeaderView(inflatedView);
commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, post.getComments(), post);
commentsListView.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
```

The adapter is a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter and I pass in the context, the List that populates the ListView, and the "post" for some reason, but it doesnt matter.

here is the error i am getting

```
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:360)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8372)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8372)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8372)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:844)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-16 12:39:58.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1562):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried setting the layout params of inflatedView to ListView.LayoutParams, FrameLayout.LayoutParams, AbsListView.LayoutParams,  nothing works.  It seems to me as if it is adding the inflatedView as the header just fine, but then later on when it attempts to invalidate the screen, it tries to go through and recycle ListView children states and it fails, that just a guess, but any thoughts?

Also, one more thing I have tried is

```
View.inflate(this, R.layout.adapter_post_note, null);
```

but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent view to null and you are good to go. No need to reference the parent of the view. Just inflate it and pass it to the method.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, i also deleted another line of code, which could have been the problem, but i'm gonna go with your answer that fixed it and not the deleted line, lol.